# SharePoint client object model returns "User Cannot Be Found" on clientContext.ExecuteQuery() method

Tags: model-view-controller, office365, csom

SharePoint client object model returns "User Cannot Be Found" on **clientContext.ExecureQuery()** method, below is sample code.

```
        ListItemCollection listItemColl = null;
        var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
        var pwd = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];

        foreach (char c in pwd)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        var spUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Office365SharepointUri"];
        var clientContext = new ClientContext(new Uri(spUri));
        var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"], securePassword);

        clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

        try
        {
            var strCamlQuery = new CamlQuery();                
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);                
            var templist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SomeValidListName");
            clientContext.Load(templist);                
            strCamlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";
            listItemColl = templist.GetItems(strCamlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItemColl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

I am giving valid credentials, even able to access SharePoint site with same supplied credentials through browser without any issue.

Dose anyone face this issue before?

**Environment:**
MVC 5 Application.
CSOM.
Visual Studio.
C#

Answer (score 4):

This is Bug in SharePoint, i spoke with SharePoint premium support.

If user who created those lists is deleted completely, when you try to access those lists CSOM throws "User cannot be found" exception, SP internally checks for user who created the list.

Solution is recreate those lists with different user. Hope SP team fix's this issue.

Thanks for your answer.